# Draw multiple line with multipe size on canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I already know how to draw multiple line on canvas

But currently I able to set only one text size for them once

And now, I wanna draw multiple line with multiple size on canvas, in details :

- Text 1 : size 16
- Text 2 : size 32
- Text 3 : size 14

I don't know how to do it actually,

People who know, Please help me more details,

Thank you,

p/s : Sample code for draw multiple line on canvas I did :

[image]

The multiple line about text size and position show wrong since I calculated wrong, I'm still checking.

```
private TextPaint mTp;

private String[] strings = {
        " Topics : Asukabu Tawain \n ",
        "512 \n ",
        "Comments \n",
        "7:30 22/12/2017"
};

private float height = 0;

public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Initialize a new Bitmap object
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inMutable = true;
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.red_circle, opt);

    mTp = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // text color - #3D3D3D
    mTp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // text shadow
    mTp.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    textWidth = mutableBitmap.getWidth();

    setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    x = (canvas.getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (canvas.getWidth() < 150)
            mTp.setTextSize(0);
        else
            mTp.setTextSize(determineMaxTextSize(strings[i], height/2));

        StaticLayout mSl = new StaticLayout(
                strings[i], mTp, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

        // get height of multiline text
        int textHeight = mSl.getHeight();

        // get position of text's top left corner
        y = (canvas.getHeight() - textHeight) / 2;

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        canvas.save();

        canvas.translate(x, y);
        mSl.draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

private int determineMaxTextSize(String str, float maxWidth){
    int size = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++ size);
    } while(paint.measureText(str) < maxWidth);

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **3 different** `TextPaint` to draw 3 different sizes of text.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = width;
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(width/2,height/2,width/2 - 10,paint);

    textPaint1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    textPaint1.setTextSize(36);
    canvas.drawText("You received",width/2 - 108,height/2 - 80,textPaint1);

    textPaint2.setTextSize(72);
    textPaint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("135",width/2 - 72,height/2,textPaint2);

    textPaint3.setTextSize(32);
    textPaint3.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("comments",width/2 - 96,height/2 + 40,textPaint3);
}
```

And another **advice** :*Don't new Object in `onDraw` method,because it will be called every time your UI updates and creating so many objects will trigger GC easily and cause bad performance.*

Comment: Your idea is great. But I need calculate `x` `y` automatically, need set Center gravity for text value also. Like image I updated in question, please take a look.